# Insert text in the form of topics in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to enter the description of my text in the form of topics. I'll insert an attached image to help them. The first image is the output generated by the code and the other is an example of what I want. This example is from the following app: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/career-pathfinder.html

Code executable:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                        title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                        
                        tabPanel("",
                                 div(
                                   style =
                                     "height: 80px;  background-color: #2C3E50; width: 100%; position:absolute;right:0;",
                                   
                                   div(
                                     style = "width: 80%; margin: auto;",
                                     
                                     h1(HTML("<u> WELCOME <b>NAME</b> </u>"),
                                        style="text-align:center; color: white;"),
                                     hr(),
                                      shiny::HTML("<br><br><center> <h2><b>EXAMPLE</b></h2> </center><br>"),
                                     h4(HTML("1-Accumsan nostra eu sodales etiam interdum lacus nullam. 
                                              2-pretium congue, dolor phasellus tincidunt metus. 
                                              3-Auctor scelerisque."),
                                        
                                        style="text-align: justify"),

                                     br(),
                                     tags$style(".navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}")))))





server <- function(input, output,session) {
  

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Example:**
[image]

Comment: You want something to happen when the user clicks on a "topic"? A link?

Comment: No, the goal is more to have a better view in the form of topics.

Comment: See my edit for another style, closer to your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is more a HTML question than a Shiny question. Here is an example:

```r
library(shiny)

CSS <- HTML("
    span.circle {
        background: turquoise;
        border-radius: 1.6em;
        -moz-border-radius: 1.6em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1.6em;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: large;
        line-height: 3.2em;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 3.2em; 
    }
    .box {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 5%;
        border-color: turquoise;
        border-width: 3px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
")

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(CSS)
    ),
    br(),
    tags$div(
        style = "display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;",
        tags$div( # box 1
            class = "box",
            style = "width: 25%;",
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$span(class = "circle", "1")
            ),
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$p(
                    style = "text-align: justify;",
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
                )
            )
        ),
        tags$div( # box 2
            class = "box",
            style = "width: 25%;",
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$span(class = "circle", "2")
            ),
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$p(
                    style = "text-align: justify;",
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
                )
            )
        ),
        tags$div( # box 3
            class = "box",
            style = "width: 25%;",
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$span(class = "circle", "3")
            ),
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$p(
                    style = "text-align: justify;",
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

For a more funny style, you can add some shadows:

```css
span.circle {
    background: turquoise;
    border-radius: 1.6em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1.6em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1.6em;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
    line-height: 3.2em;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 3.2em; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

[image]

---

## EDIT: closer boxes

```r
library(shiny)

CSS <- HTML("
    span.circle {
        background: turquoise;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 1.6em;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 1.6em; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    }
    .box {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 5%;
        border-color: turquoise;
        border-width: 3px;
        padding: 15px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        marginf-right: 10px;
    }
")

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(CSS)
    ),
    br(),
    tags$div(
        style = "display: flex; justify-content: center;",
        tags$div( # box 1
            class = "box",
            style = "width: 25%;",
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$span(class = "circle", "1")
            ),
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$p(
                    style = "text-align: justify;",
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
                )
            )
        ),
        tags$div( # box 2
            class = "box",
            style = "width: 25%;",
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$span(class = "circle", "2")
            ),
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$p(
                    style = "text-align: justify;",
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
                )
            )
        ),
        tags$div( # box 3
            class = "box",
            style = "width: 25%;",
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$span(class = "circle", "3")
            ),
            tags$div(
                style = "display: flex; justify-content: center",
                tags$p(
                    style = "text-align: justify;",
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]